# Custom class attribute that applies a different attribute to all methods

Tags: c#

I know I can create a custom class attribute like so:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
class MyClassAttribute : Attribute {
    // Logic in here to apply MyMethodAttribute to all methods
    // in the class to which this is applied.
}
```

...and I can create a custom method attribute like so:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
class MyMethodAttribute : Attribute { }
```

How can I edit the logic of `MyClassAttribute` such that it automatically applies `MyMethodAttribute` to all methods in the class that I apply it to? **Is this even possible?**

Comment: Doesn't seem possible, but if it's automatically applied to all methods in the class, why not just depend on the class attribute instead?

Comment: Perhaps look at something like postSharp, what is the function of `MyMethodAttribute`

Comment: @3dd, MyMethodAttribute is just MSTest's `TestCategory`, which is only applicable on a method level. I am trying to apply a class-level equivalent of `TestCategory`.

Comment: Please note that attributes in C# are just annotations without any direct logic that depends on the thing they are attached to. Particularly, the attribute itself gets no information whatsoever about the type they are attached to. So there simply cannot be some attribute logic that applies something to all methods of the annotated type.

Comment: @poke But there exist frameworks which interpret attributes. For example, a way of automatically applying some `IApplyTest` attribute to all existing unit tests within the NUnit framework would be very useful.

Comment: @BartoszKP But none of that logic happens within the attribute. It’s up to a different component to become *active* and *interpret* those annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it is impossible to trigger some other decoration logic as there is no access from the `Attribute` itself to the class (or method) it is applied to.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [partial methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6b0scde8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)?

You'd run the template - it'd use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) to generate partial method stubs for all methods in the class which has the attribute, and add the attribute on automatically.

Obviously it's not ideal (you have to mark your classes as partial, and you'd need one template per assembly), but it might work for you.